# python socket recv timeout does not time-out

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, timeout, settimeout, recv

Synopsis:  server hangs on socket.recv() even though a socket.settimeout() was set.

Have a simple socket based server that loops over commands (simple text messages) sent from client(s) until it receives an 'end' command.  I simulate a broken client by
- making a connection
- sending a command
- receive the result
- exit (never sending the 'end' command to server)

The whole system worked perfectly when the server/client protocol was adhered to, but with the broken client simulation the server is NOT timing out on the recv.

Relevant server code (simplified):

```
ip = '192.168.77.170'
port = 12345
args = { app specific data }

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as serverSock:
    serverSock.bind((ip, port))
    serverSock.listen()
    while True:
        sock, addr = serverSock.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=session, args=(sock, args))
        thread.name = "client {}".format(addr)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

def session(sock, args):
    sess = threading.local()
    sess.sock = sock
    sess.__dict__.update(args)

    print("-" * 60)
    print("Session opened   from={addr}.".format(addr=sock.getpeername()))
    sock.settimeout(10.0)
    while True:
        try:
            print('about to wait on recv', sock.gettimeout())
            cmd = recvString(sock)
            print('got cmd =', cmd)
            if   cmd.startswith('foo'):  doFoo(sess, cmd)
            elif cmd.startswith('bar'):  doBar(sess, cmd)
            elif cmd.startswith('baz'):  doBaz(sess, cmd)
            elif cmd.startswith('end'):  break
            else:
                raise Exception("Protocol Error: bad command '{}'".format(cmd))
        except TimeoutError as err:
            print("Error protocol timeout")
            break
        finally:
            try:
                sock.close()
            except:
                pass
            print("Session closed.")

def recvString(sock):
    buff = bytearray()
    while True:
        b = sock.recv(1)
        if b == b'\x00': break
        buff += b
    return buff.decode() if len(buff) else ''
```

When running with broken client I get

```
> about to wait on recv cmd 10.0
> got cmd = foo
> about to wait on recv cmd 10.0
```

waits forever (and has very high CPU consumption to add insult to injury)

I've RTFM'd thoroughly and multiple times, and looked at other similar SO postings and all indicate that a simple settimeout() should work.  Can't see what I'm doing wrong.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    b = sock.recv(1)
    if b == b'\x00': break
    buff += b
```

If the peer closes the connection then `sock.recv(1)` will return `b''`, i.e. no data. This situation is not accounted for.
As a result there will be an endless and busy loop where `sock.recv(1)` will return with `b''`, only to be called again and **immediately** return with `b''` etc. This also explains the high CPU.

Comment: Yup.  You were absolutely right. 
Had nothing to do with the timeout -- and it now all makes sense.  Thank-you so much.